# Task align style

Tags: tasks

Original .:
[image]
And

I want to do like this. how can I do it?
[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newlength{\taskindent}
%
\settowidth{\taskindent}{\text{m)}}
\settasks{
    item-indent=\taskindent,
    label-format=\MakeUppercase, 
    after-skip = 3ex,
}
%
\begin{document}
%
            \begin{tasks}(3)
                \task $360$
                \task $190$
                \task $209$
                \task $300$
                \task $120$
            \end{tasks}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can anyone help

Comment: Rolled back changes to the question since edit 3 entirely changed the contents of the question by replacing the original question's code with the code given as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

The following code

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newlength{\taskindent}
%
\settowidth{\taskindent}{\text{m)}}
\settasks{
    item-indent=\taskindent,
    label-format=\MakeUppercase, 
    after-skip = 3ex,
}
%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tasks}(5)
  \task*(2) $360$
  \task*(2) $190$
  \task $209$
  \task[] 
  \task*(2) $300$
  \task $120$
\end{tasks}
%
\end{document}
```

generates:
[image]

Comment: thanks for comment but When I add the after document to my code, the options are a, b, c, e, f . Not a,b,c,d,e @Luis Turcio

Comment: Can you show your preamble, because this behavior is due to something in your document

Comment: \documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}
\newlength{\taskindent}

\settowidth{\taskindent}{\text{m)}}
\settasks{
    item-indent=\taskindent,
    label-format=\MakeUppercase, 
    after-skip = 3ex,
}

\begin{document}

            \begin{tasks}(5)
  \task*(2) $360$
  \task*(2) $190$
  \task $209$
  \task[] 
  \task*(2) $300$
  \task $120$
\end{tasks}

\end{document} @Luis Turcio

Comment: @suarez I have edited my answer showing the output generated by the code with the addition of your supposed preamble. As you can see it is the desired output, so if you don't have the same it must be something in your preamble

Comment: @Luis Turcio thanks for support but see screenshot here https://ibb.co/6R1dSK0

Comment: Remember overleaf uses an outdated texlive. You can copy-paste the same code in, say, [texlive](https://texlive.net) and you will see the difference. One option could be to download the newer version of tasks and add it to your document files. I have not tested so I don't know if this suffices

Comment: thank you @Luis Turcios :)